# How to implement scripted events for videogame design?

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine

I'm building a game in C++ (using SDL) for a college project, I'm trying to figure out how to script events that happens when a player does something, or some time passes etc.

I have a and idea of how to do it but I don't want to go against how it's commonly done.

---

Right now I have a class called Obj from where enemies, items and the player are child classes, my idea is to add 3 public variables to it like this:

```
class Obj{
    int eventDeath,eventTouch,eventTalk,eventMeet;
}
```

Then I could create an Obj with eventDeath=1 and when it died it would fire event(1). event() would be something like this:

```
void event(int n){
   switch(n){
   case 1: 
      dialog("I'm dying");
      break;   
   }
}
```

I could also add invisible "Obj" in specific places for when a player walks over a certain place. I don't know if this is a good idea but I can't think of other means to do it. How is it commonly done? Also how do I keep track of events that already happened?

Answer (score 0):

An age old question to which there is probably no truely 'correct' answer. It is whatever works best for you. Take a look at the following links for information

[Why embed lua into a game engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030767/why-embed-lua-into-a-game-engine)

[How do you add a scripting language to a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-do-you-add-a-scripting-language-to-a-game)