# Can someone explain consisely why I would want or need Lua mixed with C++ for a game?

Tags: c++, lua

I've studied a bit of Lua, and I'm relatively familiar with C++ but I still don't see any real reason I would want to use Lua (or any scripting language for that matter) in conjunction with C++. If I'm already making a game in C++ (a fast language) why wouldn't I just do everything in C++? After all, I'm already familiar with C++. Why should I spend time learning a new language and how to integrate it into my C++ code? I'm sure there would be issues just getting the interface set up and working. Learning would take some time, how would it really pay off? Would it really only be beneficial to large development teams?

Comment: Do you want your users writing **mods** in C++? Neither do I.

Comment: So it's basically just for the modding community? Then 99% of developers don't even need to think about Lua. Especially not indies. I can't think of many (or any) mod-able indie games.

Comment: Story boards.  In many games, the theme or storyboard is written as a script.  This allows for quick turn around times and proof of concepts.  Things that don't change as often, such as the graphics engine, are coded in "lower level" languages.

Comment: Even if you do not care to support outside mods from your fans, it is in your best interest to make your game into a mod of your own engine. It helps you make good decisions at focusing on the essentials. Without a scripting language, your game and your engine often end up one huge blob with no useful separation. It becomes harder to pull out reusable pieces.

Comment: League of Legends uses Lua. =]

Comment: "Then 99% of developers don't even need to think about Lua" is a rather hasty generalization that suggests rationalization rather than careful analysis.

Comment: I would just like to see some practical example of how using Lua saved a developer a lot of time. I can understand how large triple A games can make use of it, but the average small indie team or solo developer?

Comment: Project Zomboid is an indie game being developed in Java. It uses Lua.

Comment: Another point I forgot to bring up: you wouldn't put images and audio in your source code, would you? Those are assets. If you think of your game's rules, lore, level layouts, maps, etc. as assets, it further helps distinguish the separation between C++ and Lua.

Comment: [My answer the last time this was asked.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12031463/501459)

Answer (score 6):

I echo what has been said, and I want to add my own thoughts as I am integrating Lua into my game engine this very moment!

It depends on what kind of game you are making, but regardless of your feelings on allowing fans to mod your game, it's just good practice to separate engine components from gameplay components.

The first major benefit is rapid iteration. The best decision I made was connecting the F5 key to reloading the Lua state (just like a browser's F5 refresh, in case that wasn't obvious). I can edit the script and then just mash F5 in my running engine to see the result right away. This is much more effective than rebuilding native code. You are less likely to lose your train of thought, and you can debug (gameplay) problems very quickly.

I find that working in Lua makes me more creative. It helps me set aside my rigid, unforgiving engineer brain and bring out my experimental, #YOLO brain. Why does my character's HP need to be carefully and precisely stored as a 32-bit integer in a C++ object? No part of the engine needs to know about that kind of information. The higher level gameplay is the only thing that cares. HP is updated only occasionally, and it relates to "the rules", not any kind of engine consideration.

Think of C++ as your master violinist and Lua as your conductor: your violinist better be really good/fast at playing the violin, but your conductor doesn't ever play the violin; he just tells your violinist to play louder/softer/faster/slower.

Lua is slow (relative to C++), but that is fine. Lua does not need to decompress an OGG into PCM in under 5ms; that is your engine's job. Lua makes extremely high level decisions: "This is the audio I want played at this moment."

I do many projects alone, and I can honestly tell you that integrating Lua is a very good thing. It creates a very clean separation between low level technical mumbo jumbo and your *actual* **game**.

Comment: I can see how being able to see changes during run-time would be very useful. Currently I use Java and that's built-in. Very nice feature.

Comment: I forgot to mention: debug console. Being able to type scripts into the engine itself is freakin' amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly for flexibility, if you want to later change the behavior of something its easier just to change your script and reload it instead of having to re-compile your server.

Here is an overview as to why Cryengine uses it(engine for the popular game series Crysis): http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC5/Script+Usage

and this is an MMORPG project that has its core in C++ and scripting in Lua: https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver/

Comment: You know? Some people get really upset if you spell LUA instead of Lua.

Comment: Did you know I did not know that? I changed my original post

Answer (score 3):

It is generally good practice to split layers of an application from each other with abstraction.

Quite often part of your application is highly performance insensitive.

If you place a scripting interface between the high performance core and the performance insensitive scriptable portion, you first gain a huge abstraction layer benefit.  If done right, no errors in the scripting portion can cause memory corruption or otherwise invoke UB.

So now that code cannot intermingle, and mistakes in it are insulated from the rest of the app.

On top of that, you now get to work in a language that makes many things (object lifetime, string manipulation, runtime modification of logic, etc) really easy.  The lower risk from errors plus the ease of expressing things can massively increase your ability to prototype new functionality, and reduce QA overhead before shipping it.

On top of that, because you have a scripting engine, your game can now "safely" rewrite itself: doing so in C++ pure would be much harder.  And rewriting yourself is a powerful tool, if dangerous (even "safely")